# Deploy Configuration/Data To Volumes When Using Docker

Tags: docker

Volumes are [recommended](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for data persistence as [the data doesn't persist after the container no longer exists](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) (*not* the same as the container has *exited*).

If you have files like configuration files and databases etc. that aren't customised by env variables you need a way to get these onto the volumes mounted in your container.

This means that docker or docker-compose are not enough for deployment by themselves as it doesn't encapsulate the whole application.

How are the rest of the files on volumes etc typically deployed in docker based applications?

e.g.

- You need to create an azure drive to mount as a volume.
- You also need to put some files on this drive

Answer (score 1):

> Containers do not persist data so volumes are needed for things like
>   configuration files and databases etc.

Containers **persist** data until you remove it implicitly (`docker system prune`) or explicitly (`docker container rm` or `docker run --rm ...`).

> This means that docker or docker-compose are not enough for
>   deployment.

Don't get an idea. Quite a lot of software is deployed in dockerized form. But actually for data persistence `volumes` are always a recommended solution over storing it in containers (because they do it explicitly)

> How are the rest of the files on volumes etc typically deployed in
>   docker based applications?

Volumes are not deployed. Deployment data is built into the image (with `ADD`/`COPY` instructions on build stage). Customizable data is supplied with volumes on running phase by users.

Comment: In practical workflows I find myself `docker rm` pretty much all the time.  Containers persist data...until you need to upgrade to a newer image or change a startup-time option, and then **data stored only in the container is lost forever**.

Comment: @DavidMaze agree, I am sure it is not safe manner to store data, but statement "Containers do not persist data" is still false

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the point about persistence. The key part of the question is how required files not part of the container are managed.